# find out if react component is rendering any value

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and need some help.

Trying to use react component `react-embed` . You must provide a single parameter `url` for this component to generate embeddable iframe for given `url`. However it operates only on some urls: if `url` is in their list of supported urls - it will get rendered, otherwise - not (no html).

I need an idea how to find out if this library will render anything or not if I'm passing any urls from my app.

In `react-embed` if no output is rendered they return `ReactEmbedVoidRenderer` which does not generate any html. It is:

```
export type ReactEmbedVoidRenderer = (
  props: ReactEmbedProps,
  state: ReactEmbedState,
  error?: Error,
) => React.ReactElement<any> | null;
```

https://github.com/streamich/react-embed/blob/master/src/ReactEmbed.tsx

How should I check if something is to be rendered ? I tried this approach, however it does not work:

```
let embeddable: boolean = false;
const element = <Embed url={item.link} ></Embed>;
if (element !== null){
    embeddable = true;
}
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What is the definition for `Embed`? Is that your own component?

Comment: No, `Embed` is not my component. I am using it in my own solution. I use it like `import Embed from 'react-embed'`

Answer (score 1):

You can not inspect the result of a render inside a component before it
actually *was* rendered.

The sub-components are only called after the current component
is already done with everything.

The only solution I can think of is to actually render it, and check if
there *was* something rendered afterwards, e.g.:

```
const WrappedEmbed = function( props ){
    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log('has content:', ref.current?.childNodes.length );
    }, []);

    return <div ref={ ref }>
        <Embed { ...props } />
    </div>
}
```